# ThingsBoard OTA update using device profile

Tags: thingsboard

I am able to update the firmware of one device, but how to update the firmware for multiple devices using the device profile.

I tried to update the firmware using the device profile but it only updates one device. also, some time OTA update stops at 99.57% and the controller restarts with old firmware some other errors also occur during the OTA update like a null callback

Comment: Moderators at strike https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389811/moderation-strike-stack-overflow-inc-cannot-consistently-ignore-mistreat-an - so I also will not do **any** (further) content/curation-related action here